# Checking if a queue exists

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I have a very basic question about Windows Azure Storage Queue errors/access.

I am trying to find out if the given storage account already contains a queue by the given name - say "queue1". I do not want to create the queue if it does not exist, and so am not keen on using the `CreateIfNotExist` method. The permissions I have given to the SAS token are - processing and Add (since all I want to do is to add a new message to the queue *only if it already exists*, and throw an error otherwise)

The problem is that when I try to get reference to a fake named queue, and add a message to it, I get a 403. 403 can also occur when the SAS token does not have permissions, so I cannot be sure what is causing the error.

Is there a way I could explicitly know if the queue exists or not?

I have tried the `BeginExist`, and `EndExist` methods but they always return false even when I can see the queue being there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The [`Get Queue Metadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179384.aspx) REST API operation will return status code 200 if the queue exists or a [Queue Service Error Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179446.aspx) otherwise.

Regarding to authorization,

> This operation can be performed by the account owner and by anyone with a shared access signature that has permission to perform this operation.

A GET request to

```
https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue?comp=metadata
```

Will return a response like:

```
Response Status:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Response Headers:
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
x-ms-approximate-messages-count: 0
Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2011 01:27:38 GMT
Server: Windows-Azure-Queue/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're getting a 403 error even if the queue does not exist. Based on what you described above, I created a simple console app. The queue does not exist in my storage account. When I try to add a message with valid SAS token, I get a 404 error:

```
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("account", "key"), false);
    CloudQueueClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    CloudQueue queue = client.GetQueueReference("non-existent-queue");
    var queuePolicy = new SharedAccessQueuePolicy();
    var sas = queue.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessQueuePolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
        Permissions = SharedAccessQueuePermissions.Add | SharedAccessQueuePermissions.ProcessMessages | SharedAccessQueuePermissions.Update
    }, null);
    StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(sas);
    var queue1 = new CloudQueue(queue.Uri, creds);
    try
    {
        queue1.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage("This is a test message"));
    }
    catch (StorageException excep)
    {
        //Get 404 error here
    }
```

Next, I made the SAS token invalid by setting it's expiry to 30 minutes before current time. Now when I run the application, I get 403 error as expected.

```
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("account", "key"), false);
    CloudQueueClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    CloudQueue queue = client.GetQueueReference("non-existent-queue");
    var queuePolicy = new SharedAccessQueuePolicy();
    var sas = queue.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessQueuePolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-30),//-30 to ensure SAS is invalid
        Permissions = SharedAccessQueuePermissions.Add | SharedAccessQueuePermissions.ProcessMessages | SharedAccessQueuePermissions.Update
    }, null);
    StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(sas);
    var queue1 = new CloudQueue(queue.Uri, creds);
    try
    {
        queue1.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage("This is a test message"));
    }
    catch (StorageException excep)
    {
        //Get 403 error here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is now an `Exists` and `ExistsAsync` (with various overloads).

Example of the former in use:

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);

        bool doesExist = queue.Exists();
```

You will want a reference to `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue` (I believe older 'cloud' assemblies may not have had these properties - initially I could only access `ExistsAsync` before I had reference the right package, once I had added the above via Nuget `Exists` also was available)

For more details see the following links:

- [Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.exists?view=azure-dotnet-legacy&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Queue_CloudQueue_Exists_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Queue_QueueRequestOptions_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_OperationContext_)
- [ExistsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.existsasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Exists` method in the `v12` as well. Wrote a simple helper method to do the check:

```
        private async Task<bool> QueueExistsAsync(QueueClient queue)
        {
            try
            {
                await queue.GetPropertiesAsync();
                return true;
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is, now. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclient.existsasync?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @HakanYildizhan add this as an answer;) And thank you!